# Woocommerce Bookings show duration instead of end date

Tags: php, woocommerce, wordpress-hook, woocommerce-bookings

On my site I sell bookable products with units of 1 day.
Customers can enter the booking start date and duration (in days).

In cart and in the order summary everything is shown correctly: booking start date and booking duration.

In *Emails*, the *my-account page* and the *thank you page* (after chekckout) what is displayed is booking start date and booking end date.
This is confusing for customers and admins.

I found a litte piece of code from WooCommerce and adapted it:

```
function modify_summary_date_20170821( $booking_date, $booking_start, $booking_end ) {
    echo 'Ankunft: ';

    return date_i18n( wc_date_format(), $booking_start );
}       
add_filter( 'wc_bookings_summary_list_date', 'modify_summary_date_20170821', 10, 3 );
```

This works so far and hides the booking end date.

But how can I add booking duration?

Any help is very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I fixed it by overriding the Woocommerce booking template files.

Have a look at this: https://woocommerce.com/document/bookings-templates/

What you can do is copy these files into your child theme and then modify the code in the copied templates to play around with how your end date is displayed.

Comment: Hi, and thank you for the idea. I have copied these files to my child theme and tried out some things. But it doesn´t work out for me...

Comment: Hi! Do you intend to do something similar to this?
https://snipboard.io/7dapZy.jpg

Comment: Hi and thanks for your input. As far as I can see there are thes two codes that have to be altered: booking-display and booking-summary-list. I can copy them to my child theme, no problem, but I have no clue how to show the duration. ...and...no, what I want to achieve is not just simply delete booking end date (which could be done with the code on top) but to REPLACE booking end date with booking duration. thanks